# Download attribute opens file instead of downloading

Tags: html, css, download

I want to test downloading a local file using the `<a>` tag in HTML. The attached code doesn't seem to download the file, instead, it opens it.

```html
<p>Interested? Download <a href="download_files/ChannelLogo.png" download>here</a></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct, however, the `download` attribute only works when you are viewing the code from a server, due to the same-origin policy of most browsers.

Are you previewing the file by double-clicking the file or directly opening it up in a browser? If the URL while previewing starts with something similar to `file://FILEPATH_HERE` or `/Users/FILEPATH_HERE`, you are opening the file rather than serving the file. If so, you should run your code from within a localhost setup to test. That may involve running a server locally, or using [an editor extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) to spin up a project-based server. Once your URL starts with http:// or https:// the download will work as intended.

Alternatively, you could upload the project somewhere on the web.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where the file is located and how files are being served.

Either way, whether it is a plain static website with local files or being served by a server, you might need to check the href again to make sure it is correct.

Could be something small like `/download_files/ChannelLogo.png` instead of `download_files/ChannelLogo.png`.

Edit after question update:
Yes answer by Riley is right: it will only download if you are using a server. You could use a server like [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/about/) to run and test what you would like to do.

Otherwise you could look into [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/) if you would like to work with the filesystem more directly, all depending on what it is you would like to do with your program.